# ArgumentException when trying to implement a Login (ASP.NET Core Project)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, argumentexception

I tried to implement a Login in my ASP.NET Core Web Applikation, which uses Data from a SQL Database to verify the Login.
I created a Service Class which should get the Usernames and the Passwords from the Database and then I am trying to compare them to the Login-Information.
However when i try to test it I keep getting the following Exception:

**ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.**[image]

The method where I am trying to compare the values looks like this:

```
 private async Task<ApplicationUser> AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
  
        var loginName = await _loginService.GetUsernameAsync(username);
        var loginPassword = await _loginService.GetPasswordAsync(password);



        if (username.Equals(loginName.Username))
        {
            if(password.Equals(loginPassword.Password))
            {
                return new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Username = loginName.Username,
                    Password = loginPassword.Password
                    //FullName = "Name"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like to see your _loginService.GetPasswordAsync(password);  I am wondering how you can get password without userName.

Comment: public async Task<Users> GetPasswordAsync(string password)
        {
            return await _context.Users
                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Password == password);
        }

Comment: But in a real life the most users have the same password. You need to use a username too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error. Replace

```
if (username.Equals(loginName.Username))
        {
            if(password.Equals(loginPassword.Password))
            {
```

with

```
if ( loginName!= null && username == loginName.UserName 
         && loginPassword !=null && password==loginPassword.Password)
```

and by the way fix your password query too. You don't need 2 actions for this:

```
public async Task<Users> GetPasswordAsync(string userName,string password)
 {
 return await _context.Set<Users>().Where(e => e.UserName==userName 
                        && e.Password == password).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed forgot to check if the strings are null.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept  if it's working.

Comment: The main Problem why I got this Exception was that I didnt get the Connection String properly in one Method. Because of that he couldnt validate the Values from the DB

Comment: Just don't use equals for the strings anymore. It's very tricky.